# How to check for value ignoring whitespaces?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

Client sends this object:

```js
const CLIENT = {
  username: "@johndoe12",
  nickname: "John Doe",
  password: "1234"
}
```

Node.js:

```js
...
const {
    rows: [{ exists }],
} = await pgPool.query(
    "SELECT exists (SELECT true FROM users WHERE username=($1) AND nickname=($2) );",
    [CLIENT.username, CLIENT.nickname]
);
if (exists) {

    res.json({
        status: "failed",
        message: "User with that username or nickname already exist.",
    });
} else if (!exists) {
//create user
...
}
```

`//.replaceAll() removes all whitespaces`

Problem: Whitespaces count as valid string, I thought about `.replaceAll(/\s/g, "")`, but the string would be saved as "JohnDoe" with no space and reusing it would be a problem.

```
{username: "@johndoe12 ", {"nickname": "John Doe   "}}  is not same as {username: "@johndoe12", nickname: "John Doe"}?
```

result:

```
5   "@Bob"  "Bob Carla "    "123"
6   "@Bob"  "Bob Carla  "   "123"
7   "@Bob"  "Bob Carla   "  "123"
```

Comment: replace(nickname, ' ', '')=replace($2, ' ', '') ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking, but if you want to ignore leading and training blanks, you can use the PostgreSQL function `trim`:

```
... WHERE trim(nickname) = trim('John Doe  ')
```

If you want to remove all blanks, try

```
... WHERE translate(nickname, ' ', '') = translate('John  Doe ', ' ', '')
```

Comment: ```"John Doe"``` is not same as  ```"     John     Doe"```

Comment: As a result I think the db is returning ```false``` value and creating a new user

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trim blacks only on sides exclude spaces between words, you can trim input on your own (on backend side) like this:

```js
const trimLeft  = str => str[0] === ' ' 
  ? trimLeft(str.slice(1)) 
  : str;
const trimRight = str => str[str.length - 1] === ' '
  ? trimRight(str.slice(0, -1))
  : str;
  
const trim = str => trimLeft(trimRight(str));


const results = [
  trim('Bob Carla'),
  trim('Bob Carla  '),
  trim('   Bob Carla  '),
  trim(' Bob    Carla  '),
];

for (const result of results) {
  console.log(result, result.length);
}
```